# Limit Connections to Database with Entity Framework C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, connection-string, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure database that is limited to 60 concurrent connections. My issue is that I have several crawlers that populate this database to be consumed by our website using Entity Framework.

It does not take long for multiple crawlers to exhaust all of the connections and error out. I have tried setting the max pool size value in the connection string, but this does not seem to enforce any restrictions on the actual database connections.

I could wrap the `DbContext` in a singleton, but then I would be limiting the entire crawler to a single connection.

Are there any other ways to achieve this?

Comment: What version of EF are you using? In conjunction with your `Max Pool Size=60;` in your connection string, are you setting `Pooling=true;`? *(although, that said `true` should be the default setting anyway)*

Comment: Are you not releasing your connection after you have finished with it?

Comment: @GeoffJames Yes Pooling is set to true.  I have tried setting Max Pool Size =1; to see if i could limit the connections.  It still spawns more connections as needed though.  I am currently using EF 6.1.3.  I tried Core but the group by issue makes it completely unusable.

Comment: @JamieR Everything in our repository is wrapped in a using statement.  The code takes advantage of the TPL Library so it is not uncommon for it to crawl 10 different customers at the same time.  With 10 or so boxes going it eventually runs out.

Comment: @mscard02 Just wanted to make sure ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to limit concurrent access to a shared resource. Usually a [Semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29) is used for this.

To do this across a single box or a single app you could use [Semaphore or SemaphoreSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6zx288a.aspx)

However if the clients are running on different boxes the natural place to place the semaphore would be the SQL Server itself. See [this article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Miscellaneous/2649/) for one way of implementing it. The app would need to call the proc to acquire the lock before accessing the database using the `DbContext`. The semaphore limit would need to be 59 to keep one connection for reading the semaphore.